# your idea for a multilingual database model for non-structured html content?

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, content-management-system

i code a small very specific cms in php/mysql/jquery right now. the project have to be in german+english - so store these informations in separate fields : title_de, title_en ..., category_de, category_en and so on. pretty easy.

now there will be some fields for html content where i have to store a combination of unordered image + text combinations. i do it like this right now :

```
<img>text<img><img>text<img><img>text<img>text<div>otherstuff</div>text<img>
```

so pretty random html elements no structure ...

so a user will have to copy this structure after creating it to another text-area for another language and translate it.

i dont like the idea to store the "structure" and the "double parts e.g. the images" twice . this would work for 2 languages - but what if its 10 languages.

is there an logic and easy way to separate the structure and how would you model that in a database ?

Comment: Design questions tend to become discussion questions and can also be primarily opinion-based. Primarily opinion based questions do not fit within the scope of StackOverflow.

Comment: Not 100% sure I get your question but...  What about a FORM where the user uploads the file and has to provide the description in both English and German.  Then in your database, each file row has 3 values: image file location, English description, German description.  So your image is there only once.  If you need another language, add a column for the X language description.

Comment: @chris85: propose something else then.  Such an answer does not help.

Comment: Have all the columns, then have a column for language. This will reduce the clutter of tens/hundreds of columns. You can have row id repeat, but make `id` and `language` a unique pairing.

Comment: @Nic - its not about have a description for each image. its a bout free html - as you can see in my example . even more - <h1> and so on.  so i can not create a structure based on some images and choose the right language. i wish it would be so easy. there is no limit - some images will be there in various sittuations with different text. or no text. or 5 x same image ... but sometimes text, sometimes not ... u get what i mean ?#

Comment: @Nic I have, multiple columns are never a good DB structure. If you are duplicating columns, or grouping data the structure usually should be re-thought.

Comment: @Lexi - im talking about a propper database design. an entity relationship model. i think this is totaly the scope of stackoverflow. as you can script things in a different way - you can structure things in different ways. some are better, some are worse. dont get why this is not the scope of this platform :(

Comment: so basicly i wana save randomly structured html and exclude the text-content. seems this is not possible ?

Comment: I've seen database design questions get closed before as primarily opinion-based. Not everyone sees best practice in the same way. There are some standards, but there are also some gray areas, which can make this type of question too open-ended.

Answer (score 0):

I think what your looking for is called as internationalisation and localisation.

For that you may not create any new column or any other tables in database. Even you can handle with language file. Since you told that yours is small project it will work fine.

You should really use any good library like https://github.com/Philipp15b/php-i18n which is having good attention in git hub.

Even I have a solution of using basic one.

> NOTE : Since I wont be using any caching technique to save the
>   languages there may be performance issues. Please note I will recommend using any good library. Mine is just an idea for the sake of implementation. You can enhance based on it.

**en.php**

```
$language = array(
    'Hello' => 'Hello!',
    'HtmlText' => '<h1> HTML </h1>'
);
```

**fr.php**

```
$language = array(
    'Hello' => 'Bonjor'
    'HtmlText' => '<h1> HTML </h1>'
);
```

In your page now you can implement the following way

Eg:

Advice : Make sure you handle your HTML encoding while displaying.

```
/* Validate whether $_GET['lang'] is set or not. 
Whether your havig any language of that specif or not
Then use the following way to implement
 */

URL : http://127.0.0.1/project/?lang=en

include_once $_GET['lang'].'php'

echo $language['Hello']; //Irrespective which ever language you use it will load
```